# Why do php tags shoot up during weekends?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-watching, trends

This has been bugging me for some time.

I always like to check the number of tags the top tier languages get on any given day.

It always struck me as odd that, while **php** generally stays at #3 when compared to **java** and **c#**(on weekdays), it **shoots up** on weekends to get quite ahead of the other two.

I wonder **why** that is so. I've thought up of a few **possible answers:**

**ONE** People work on other platforms on weekdays on their regular jobs then switch to php on weekends for freelancing work;

**TWO** People work with other languages on weekdays but want to study/learn PHP, so they do it on weekends;

**THREE** Could this show that, while programmers *have to* work with language A, B or C in their work, they *like* working with PHP?

I'll leave this for you guys now. Have fun!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a lot of people who aren't programmers full-time, that are trying to break into web development in their free time.  So the weekend sees them doing their work and needing answers.

Web Development seems to a lot of people to be an easy way to do something on the side.

Answer (score 7):

Monday morning for me is Sunday night for everyone in the US (and other places), so time zone differentials also come into it.

Beyond what you've noticed, I've seen that many "help urgently needed" questions in PHP tend to appear over the weekend (as well as the subsequent enraged-keep-re-asking-the-same-thing syndrome). This would strongly suggest people taking work home over the weekend that should have been done the previous week.

I don't think this is at all *exclusive* to PHP, but I've yet to meet a LISP programmer who pulls their hair out on Sundays, at least not for their day job :)

Our observations are partly, if not mostly an artifact of PHP being one of the most popular tags, IMHO.

Comment: When, in your experience, do LISP programmers generally pull their hair out? :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: They can't; all the hair his hidden below twenty-four layers of parentheses.

Comment: @Cody lisp programmers have a semi-metallic exo-skeleton with no hair at all. They are 'closed'.

Comment: (((((((((()))))))))) you guys!